# Файлы произвольного доступа. Не понимаю как смещать указатель на файл

Tags: c

```
/* Эта программа открывает файл letters.txt и печатает
в него буквы от A до Z. После этого программа
с помощью цикла считывает буквы в обратном порядке от
Z до A и выводит их на экран */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE * fptr;
main()
{
 char letter;
 int i;
 fptr = fopen("C:\\users\\deanwork\\documents\\
 letters.txt","w+");
 if (fptr == 0)
 {
 printf("При открытии файла произошла ошибка.\n");
 exit(1);
 }
 for (letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++)
 {
 fputc(letter, fptr);
 }
 puts("Завершена запись букв от A до Z");
 // Чтение файла в обратной последовательности
 fseek(fptr, -1, SEEK_END); // Минус 1 байт с конца
 printf("Данные файла в обратном порядке:\n");
 for (i = 26; i > 0; i--)
 {
 letter = fgetc(fptr);
 // Чтение буквы и возврат на 2 позиции
 fseek(fptr, -2, SEEK_CUR);
 printf("The next letter is %c.\n", letter);
 }
 fclose(fptr); // Повторимся, всегда закрывайте файлы
 return(0);
}
```

Не могу понять почему в строке `fseek(fptr, -2, SEEK_CUR);` используется смещение на две позиции назад(байта), возьмем строку текста **Ашот**, допустим мой указатель указывает на букву **т**, чтобы напечатать букву **о** нужно же сместиться назад на 1 байт, почему тогда нужно смещаться на 2 байта?

Comment: Внимание, вопрос: если ваш указатель указывает на букву "т", то какую букву вы только что прочитали?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov наверное букву т

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, и к чему был этот вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос был к тому, что ответ на него - букву "о".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fgetc,  кроме чтения символа,  смещает указатель в файле на одну позицию вперед.  Отсюда очевидно: для того,, чтобы прочитать символ,  стоящий перед только что прочитанным,  нужно сместить указатель на две позиции назад.

Comment: Спасибо, это не учел.